# Ejecutar funcion javascript después de completar otra función

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

tengo el siguiente escenario:

1. Recibir variables del server.
2. Seleccionar en un dropdown uno de los valores de una variable del punto anterior.
3. Dicho dropdown tiene un evento "onchange" que genera los elementos del siguiente dropdown (carga de datos en cascada).
4. El segundo dropdown debe tener otro valor de una de las variables (punto 1) seleccionado .
5. Ejecutar un submit.

HTML

```
<select id="SelectID" name="SelectName" onchange="LlamarFuncion()">
  <option value='Los Angeles'>Los Angeles</option>
  <option value='San Bernardino'>San Bernardino</option>  
  <option value='Riverside'>Riverside</option>
  <option value='Orange'>Orange</option>  
</select>
<select id="SelectID2" name="SelectDetail">
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
function LlamarFuncion(){
   //Esto demora
}
</script>
```

Intenté hacerle un bind, un trigger y no funcionó. Sucede que `LlamarFuncion` demora un poco, por lo que poner un setTimeout() tampoco sería una buena opción.

Cabe mencionar que el código se encuentra en un `document ready` por lo cual se ejecutará a buen ritmo.

Comment: LlamarFuncion usa el valor de SelectName para traerse las opciones de SelectDetail mediante ajax?

Comment: Acabo de ver que era una pregunta con autorespuesta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilizando jQuery se puede lograr ello mediante:

```
//Esto hará que se defina el primer valor y con ello se ejecutará "LlamarFuncion"
$("#SelectID option[value='"+UnoDeLosValoresDeUnaTusVariables+"']").attr("selected",true);

//De manera general, se trabaja así:
$.when(function1()).then(function2());

//En este caso, sería de este modo:
$.when(LlamarFuncion()).then(function(){
    $("#SelectID2 option[value='"+OtroDeLosValoresDeUnaTusVariables+"']").attr("selected",true); 
});
```

Que la fuerza os acompañe :D

Referencia: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: Puede usar [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) solo si `LlamarFuncion()` devuelve un `deferred`. Además dado que usas `.then`, la `fn2` solo se ejecutara si el `deferred` es resuelto (`eg: dfd.resolve()`).

Comment: exacto, de eso se trata :D gracias por especificar :D

Comment: Yo creo que todo eso se puede (y debe) hacer con promesas. Los enfoques de jQuery sobre los Deferred y then-ables recién se volvieron Promise/A+ compliant en la versión 3, y no corre para todos los métodos.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    // bind change event to select
    $('#mySelect').on('change', function () {
        var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
       myFunction();
    }
});
```

creo que no es seguro ejecutar funciones desde las etiquetas espero y te sirva. Este ejemplo funciona más rapido que cargar directamente de la etiqueta