# ¿Cómo hago que se ejecute un método segundos después de generarse cierto evento con JS?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo un formulario en el cual tengo el `select id=empleado` que depende del valor de `select id=sede` para llenarse y habilitarse o deshabilitarse, yo ya tengo el `método` que se llama para llenar `empleado` y que lo inhabilite sí el valor de `sede` está en 0, pero tengo un `button type="reset"` que limpia todos los campos y deja el valor de `sede` 0, pero el `método` no se ejecuta ya que el se llama con un `onchange` en `sede`, y sí hago un `onclick` en el `button` pues no hace el cambio porque cuando se presiona, el valor de `sede` es distinto a 0. La solución que puede funcionar es que se ejecute el `método` al segundo después de haberle dado click al `button`, pero no sé como se hace, les agradecería su ayuda. Dejo el código del formulario html y el método en jquery

`HTML`

```
<form action="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=guardarInser" onsubmit="return validarCampos()" name="formRegistro" method="POST">
    <div class='container justify-content-center shadow p-5 mb-1 mt-n1 bg-white rounded' style= "width: 800px">            
        <div id="errores" class="alert-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-g align-content-centerroup row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="fecha" class="col-form-label">Fecha:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" onchange="llenarEmpleados()" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" max="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" id="fecha" name="fecha">
            </div>
            <label for="sede" class="col-form-label">Sede:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" onchange="llenarEmpleados()" id="sede" name="sede" >
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar sede</option>
                    <?php 
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($sedes); $i++) { 
                            echo "<option value='{$sedes[$i]['id_sede']}'>{$sedes[$i]['sede']}</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>                 
        </div>                                    
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="empleado" class="col-form-label">Empleado:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar empleado</option>
                    <?php 
                        for ($i=0; $i < count($empleados); $i++) { 
                            echo "<option value='{$empleados[$i]['id_empleado']}'>{$empleados[$i]['nombres']} {$empleados[$i]['apellidos']}</option>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="asistencia" class="col-form-label">Asistencia:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="asistencia" name="asistencia"> 
                        <option value="0">Seleccionar asistencia</option>
                        <?php
                            for($i=0; $i < count($asistencias); $i++){
                                echo "<option value='{$asistencias[$i]['id_asistencia']}'>{$asistencias[$i]['siglas']}</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                </select>
            </div>           
        </div>                                    
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="nota" class="col-form-label">Nota:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-5 mr-3'>
                <textarea name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>                                                
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
            <div class="justify-content-center">                
                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-4 btn-md" style="width: 150px" type="submit">Registrar</button>            
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-md" role="button" style="width: 150px" href="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=todos" >Cancelar</a>            
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-end">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" type="reset">Limpiar</button>            
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

`JavaScript` donde lleno el `select`

```
<script> 
function llenarEmpleados(){
    var sede = $("#sede").val();
    var fecha = $("#fecha").val();
    var parametros = {
        'sede' : sede,
        'fecha' : fecha            
    };

    if(sede != 0 && fecha != ""){
        $.ajax({
            data: parametros,
            url: '/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=llenarEmpleados',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response){
                $("#empleado").html(response);
                console.log(response);
                $("#empleado").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $("#empleado").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu javascript.

Comment: Listo, ahí está

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu problema u.u

Comment: Espera trato de simplificarlo un poco

Comment: Tu lo que quieres es que cuando oprimas reset ambos select queden sin valor seleccionado?

Comment: Eh no, sino que cuando se oprima el reset se ejecute un método digamos unos segundos después para que así pueda tomar el valor del `select` ya después de haberse reseteado @BenderPaisa

Comment: Revisa esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55272/822

Comment: No, lo siento, sigo sin entenderte :c

Comment: @fredyfx No es tan así, ya que no estoy ejecutando dos funciones, sino solamente una y la otra ya es propia del `button type="reset"`

Comment: Lo que se me ocurrió, sería que al momento de darle click al botón que deshabilite el `select` con una función ya que se da por entendido el otro va a tomar el valor de 0

Comment: @BenderPaisa xd No pasa nada, es complicado de explicar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el TimeOut

```js
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    //Despues de 3 segundos hacer algo aqui!
    alert("Ejcutar siguiente metodo!"); 
  }, 3000 /* tiempo de espera ejm: 3 segundos*/);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Ejecutar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, lo hice en el mismo onclick, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo haria otra funcion que se encarge de limpiar todo.  Algo asi:

```js
function llenarEmpleados(){
    var sede = $("#sede").val();
    var fecha = $("#fecha").val();
    var parametros = {
        'sede' : sede,
        'fecha' : fecha            
    };

    if(sede != 0 && fecha != ""){
       
                $("#empleado").html("<option value='"+sede+"'>empleado"+sede+"</option>");
               
                $("#empleado").attr("disabled", false);
            
     
    }else{
        $("#empleado").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}
function limpiar() {
  $("#sede").val(0);
  $("#fecha").val("");
  $("#empleado").html("<option value='0'>Seleccionar empleado</option>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=guardarInser" onsubmit="return validarCampos()" name="formRegistro" method="POST">
    <div class='container justify-content-center shadow p-5 mb-1 mt-n1 bg-white rounded' style= "width: 800px">            
        <div id="errores" class="alert-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-g align-content-centerroup row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="fecha" class="col-form-label">Fecha:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <input type="date" class="form-control" onchange="llenarEmpleados()"   id="fecha" name="fecha">
            </div>
            <label for="sede" class="col-form-label">Sede:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" onchange="llenarEmpleados()" id="sede" name="sede" >
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar sede</option>
                    <option value='1'>sede1</option>
                    <option value='2'>sede2</option>
                </select>
            </div>                 
        </div>                                    
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="empleado" class="col-form-label">Empleado:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4 mr-3'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="empleado" name="empleado" disabled="disabled">
                    <option value="0">Seleccionar empleado</option>
                    
                </select>
            </div>
            <label for="asistencia" class="col-form-label">Asistencia:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-4'>
                <select type="text" class="custom-select" id="asistencia" name="asistencia"> 
                        <option value="0">Seleccionar asistencia</option>
                        
                </select>
            </div>           
        </div>                                    
        <br>
        <div class="form-group row ml-1 justify-content-center">
            <label for="nota" class="col-form-label">Nota:</label>
            <div class='col-sm-5 mr-3'>
                <textarea name="nota" id="nota" class="form-control" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
            </div>                                                
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row justify-content-center">
            <div class="justify-content-center">                
                <button class="btn btn-primary mr-4 btn-md" style="width: 150px" type="submit">Registrar</button>            
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-md" role="button" style="width: 150px" href="/Jomar/users_control/controller/ControlAsisController.php?action=todos" >Cancelar</a>            
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-end">
                <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" type="reset" onClick="limpiar()">Limpiar</button>            
            </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Solo que, `empleado` pues se vaciaría y se deshabilitaría, pero pues lo de limpiar los campos, pues ya lo hace el `button type="reset"`

Comment: Y pues ahora que lo mencionaste así, se me dio la idea de que simplemente deshabilite `empleado` cuando se presione el botón,  ya que se da por entendido que cuando se presiona el botón todos los valores se restablecen y en este caso quedan todos vacios o en 0, excepto la fecha