# Cómo llamar una función javascript después de que se ejecute otra con javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, callback

La cosa está que tengo una funcion "a()" en un .js externo que no puedo editar y necesito ejecutar una función mía después de que se ejecute esa.
Encontré esto en internet

```
$.when(function1()).then(function2());
```

La cosa con esto es que es jQuery y yo no uso jQuery. Necesito hacerlo con javascript puro. Alguien sabe cómo puedo hacerlo?

EDIT: Pidieron mi código, no sé por qué es importante pero aquí lo pongo.

```
function a(){
alert("Hola función a");
return false;
}
    
function mifuncion(){
alert("Hola función mifunción");
}
```

**NOTA**: No tengo acceso a function a() por lo tanto no puedo editarle nada. A function miFuncion sí tengo acceso.

Comment: creo que necesitamos quie agregues tu codigo para decirte que se puede hacer, cambiando algo parecido nativo seria algo como `Promise.resolve(function1()).then...`

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. Tú crees? yo no creo que sea necesario ni verdaderamente importante pero de igual forma lo haré.

Comment: Lo que es necesario es saber como funciona **exactamente** `a( )`: ¿ Devuelve una *promesa* ? ¿ Recibe una *calback* como parámetro ? ¿ No devuelve nada, ni usa ninguna callback, pero realiza código *asíncrono* ?

Comment: Juanjo se me adelantó unos segundos.. esto es lo que estaba escribiendo: la función a() devuelve algo asíncrono como una promesa? Porque si no es asíncrona, podrías simplemente hacer: `a(); miFuncion();`

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/55272/822 con respuesta incluida

Comment: Hola. @JackNavaRow y Juano, la función es tal cuál la vez, ejecuta un alert y ya.

Comment: @fredyfx de ahí saqué el ejemplo con jQuery. Necesito que sea con javascript puro.

Comment: @JackNavaRow revisé Promise.resolve pero eso me ejecuta la función a() también. Necesito que esté escuchando a a() para que cuando se ejecute (porque lo ejecutan varios componentes a los que tampoco tengo acceso) yo ejecutar mi función. Alguna idea, compañeros?

Comment: que hace a() retorna algun  valor es tipo void ??

Comment: @JackNavaRow retorna false siempre

Comment: Se puede cachar el false y desde ahí saber qué función lo lanzó?

Comment: @Juanjo Yo no ejecuto a() literalmente. Lo ejecuta de manera nativa el aplicativo que uso. Y como he puesto, no puedo editar la función a(). Necesito de alguna manera estar observando a a() y cuando esta se termine de ejecutar entonces yo mandar llamar mifuncion()

Comment: Comenta la idea, por favor a ver qué tal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es poder ejecutar algo después de que tú llames a `a`, podrías encapsular `a` y agregarle un callback opcional:

```
function a () {
    alert("Hola desde a");
    return false;
}

--------------

// asignas la funcionalidad de 'a' en otra función
var b = a;

// sobreescribes 'a' encapsulando su llamada
a = function (callback) {
    // llamas a la función 'b'
    b();

    // si te han pasado un callback, lo ejecutas
    if (callback) { callback(); }
}
    
function mifuncion () {
    // ahora cada vez que llame a "a", puedo pasarle un callback
    a(function () {
        alert("Hola después de ejecutar a");
    })
}
```

Si lo que quieres es enterarte de que desde cualquier sitio alguien llama a `a`, de una forma muy parecida podrías:

```
function a () {
    alert("Hola desde a");
    return false;
}

--------------

// asignas la funcionalidad de 'a' en otra función
var b = a;

// sobreescribes 'a' encapsulando su llamada
a = function () {
    // llamas a la función 'b'
    b();

    // TODO haces lo que quieras para enterarte de que 'a' ha sido llamado
    // por ejemplo, llamar a 'mifuncion'
    mifuncion();
}
    
function mifuncion () {
    alert("Hola función mifunción");
}
```

Comment: lo unico que le agregaria es retornar es la funcion a a su nombre original

Answer (score 2):

Si te he entendido bien podrías lograrlo usando una `Promise` y pasando el `resolve` de la `Promise` para que la función b se ejecute en un `then`, algo así:

```js
new Promise(function(resolve) {

resolve(a());

}).then(function(result) {

b();

})

function a() {
  alert("Hola función a");
}

function b() {
  alert("Hola función mifunción");
}
```

Ojala te funcione. Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Si no entendí mal el problema, creo que lo mas fácil, es llamar y gestionar la función a() dentro de tu función mifuncion().

```js
function a(){
  alert("Hola función a");
  return false;
}
    
function mifuncion(){
  a();
  alert("Hola función mifunción");
}

mifuncion();
```